# Renaming a sequence of files to remove file hash in brackets in OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, rename, batch-processing

it seems that my Google-fu is weak, as I have been unable to find an answer or example to strip out some unwanted file hash data from a series of file names in OS X.

Here are the first three file names to demonstrate the problem that I am having -

```
Video File - 01 [B8CC68AD].avi
Video File - 02 [E5BCDDA2].avi
Video File - 03 [390CC36E].avi
```

As you can see, the text to be removed is consistently 8 characters long and contained within square brackets, but this is beyond the wildcard-less limitation of Automator, so I have been trying to figure it out in Terminal. However I am not sure how to rename a sequence of files in this way. If anybody could spare some wisdom I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

With [Perl rename](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) :

```
rename 's/\[.*?\]//' *.avi
```

[image: warning]
 **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command

```
$ file $(readlink -f $(type -p rename))
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)